# How to compile custom kernel for Raspberry Pi

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm trying to run the [Ubuntu 14 Raspberry Pi ARM image](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) in QEMU, and for that I need the kernel that matches the version used in the image.

If I mount the image and run `file vmlinuz` I see:

```
vmlinuz: symbolic link to `boot/vmlinuz-3.18.0-20-rpi2'
```

so I'm interpreting that to mean that image uses kernel version 3.18.0.

Using [this guide](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/tree/master/tools), I tried compiling this version of the kernel, which I'm doing with:

```
TOOLCHAIN=arm-linux-gnueabihf

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git libncurses5-dev gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
cd linux
# checking out 3.18.0+ branch - change it if you want to change kernel version
# for kernel specific hash, have a looks at : https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/commits/rpi-3.18.y
# git checkout 1bb18c8f721ef674a447f3622273f2e2de7a205c
make ARCH=arm versatile_defconfig
cat >> .config << EOF
CONFIG_CROSS_COMPILE="$TOOLCHAIN"
CONFIG_CPU_V6=y
CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_411920=y
CONFIG_ARM_ERRATA_364296=y
CONFIG_AEABI=y
CONFIG_OABI_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_PCI=y
CONFIG_SCSI=y
CONFIG_SCSI_SYM53C8XX_2=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y
CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT=y
CONFIG_TMPFS=y
CONFIG_INPUT_EVDEV=y
CONFIG_EXT3_FS=y
CONFIG_EXT4_FS=y
CONFIG_VFAT_FS=y
CONFIG_NLS_CODEPAGE_437=y
CONFIG_NLS_ISO8859_1=y
CONFIG_FONT_8x16=y
CONFIG_LOGO=y
CONFIG_VFP=y
CONFIG_CGROUPS=y
CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835=y
CONFIG_MMC_BCM2835_DMA=y
CONFIG_DMADEVICES=y
CONFIG_DMA_BCM2708=y
EOF

make savedefconfig
#make -j 4 -k ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${TOOLCHAIN}- menuconfig
make -j 4 -k ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${TOOLCHAIN}- bzImage
cd ..
cp linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage kernel-qemu-3.18
```

However, when I go to run this kernel with qemu-system-arm, I get the error:

```
Error: unrecognized/unsupported processor variant (0x410fb767).
```

Also, I'm noticing the make command removes my changes to the `.config` file.

How do I fix this error?

Can I use the vmlinuz file from the image instead of compiling my own from scratch?

Comment: Try this http://lostindetails.com/blog/post/Compiling-a-kernel-module-for-the-raspberry-pi-2